# PySide/PyQt5 QSettings not saving to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

Tags: python, windows, persistence, pyside2, qsettings

I am attempting to save appliction & "organization" specific data, and chose to use the `QSettings` class. Things overall work well, however I've found that I cannot save to the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` registry, which is the location for `QSettings` when you set the `QSettings` scope to System. I have made a stripped down app to try and save to all four locations, found below.

The `application_user_settings` and `company_user_settings` save in the correct place, but the `application_system_settings` and `company_system_settings` do not save at all. Furthermore, in the below script, I have printed out the `QSettings` `fileName` for each instance, and they print out the expected paths.

I thought this might be a adminstrator privileges problem, so I reopened Pycharm, the IDE I'm using, and ran it as an administrator which is supposed to run all python files as an administrator. Even after this, I'm still having the same problem.

Does anybody know why `QSettings` isn't saving to the system scope properly?

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PySide2.QtCore import QSettings

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = QMainWindow()
window.show()


application_user_settings = QSettings('Company_Name', 'Application_Name')
application_user_settings.setValue('bruh_user', 1.0)
print(application_user_settings.fileName())  # \HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Company_Name\Application_Name

company_user_settings = QSettings('Company_Name')
company_user_settings.setValue('bruh_user', 1.0)
print(company_user_settings.fileName())  # \HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Company_Name\OrganizationDefaults

application_system_settings = QSettings(QSettings.SystemScope, 'Company_Name', 'Application_Name')
application_system_settings.setValue('bruh_system', 2.0)
print(application_system_settings.fileName())  # \HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Company_Name\Application_Name

company_system_settings = QSettings(QSettings.SystemScope, 'Company_Name')
company_system_settings.setValue('bruh_system', 2.0)
print(company_system_settings.fileName())  # \HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Company_Name\OrganizationDefaults


app.exec_()
```

**HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE**

[image]

**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Running pycharm as administrator apparently does not actually run python scripts with admin privilege's.  You need to open a command window as admin and then run your python script through that.  I just came across the same problem and this technique solved it.  In previous version of python2 or qt4 (not sure which, but probably qt4) ... the code would update the registry without having to run with admin.  This is actually annoying in my use case.  I wish to update at SystemScope without the need for admin :(